# Can impurities in a working fluid increase the efficiency of the system?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am going to be specific here.In a steam driven turbine, water is used a working fluid.The liquid converted to gas and then the steam causing the turbine to work.The heat added to convert the liquid to gas is Enthalpy of vaporization.So now , if sugar or salt is added to the water , it will raise its boiling point , Thus an increase in the enthalpy of vaporization , which in turn means that more heat is needed to covert the water to steam and now the steam will have more energy than if we used water without salt or sugar.Thus more energized steam will give an increased output.Will this be the case or not?

Comment: Note that steam boilers for power generation already have a wide variety of additives (called "conditioners") in the water being boiled. These chemicals are tailored to perform may tasks: corrosion inhibition, oxygen scavenging, pH adjustment, scale buildup inhibition, maintaining precipitates in suspension, and so on. Their presence does not materially affect the power output inherent in the boiling process.